# Is the oscillating EM field and probability interference caused by the same wave property of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, wave-particle-duality

Light travels as an oscillating EM wave. It can also interfere with itself to create wavelike probability distributions. Are these waves behaviors one in the same, just different shades of the wave nature of light? Or are these two separate phenomenon and light just happens to exhibit both?

Hopefully an analogy can better illustrate what I'm asking. If I pluck a guitar string and leave my finger on it I will see the string vibrate with a wave pattern and I will feel the string against my finger with a pressure pattern like a wave. Both things are sensed because of one wavelike thing, the string getting plucked.

Now, if I drop something in water two things also can happen. I can see the water oscillate transversely and I will hear sound because of longitudinal air displacement. The event had two wavelike outcomes, water ripples and sound. However, the mechanisms causing these phenomenon are different and it is just because of the circumstances that they are sensed together.

In the case of light's EM fields and probability distributions is it more like the first or second analogy?

*Sorry I know the analogy isn't particularly strong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light interference is linked to the phase of the EM wave. It is contructive when signals are in phase, destructive when they are out of phase.

For an oscillating EM wave, the oscillating part refers to phase oscillations. Frequency and amplitude (at least in a void) are constants, phase is oscillating.

So yes, it is the same phenomenon.

The image at the [Optical interference paragraph on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation)#Optical_interference) shows this clearly. The EM wave shown travels a bit more, so its phase oscillates a bit more, and when they are superposed interference is due to being in phase or out of phase.